# Laravel not showing index.php

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new in Laravel, I made virtual host http://example.com and installed Laravel in folder of this domain but when I try to access this domain I get this 
[image]

Comment: Show your VirtualHost configuration, and make sure the vhosts module is enabled in your httpd.conf

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example"
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 ErrorLog "logs/www.example.com.domain-error.log"
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is your `VirtualHost` setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example" ## <-- pointed to wrong folder
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 
    ErrorLog "logs/www.example.com.domain-error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

You didn't point it to the `public` folder. It should be (These are minimum requirements)

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example/public"
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You should point it to the `public` folder because `index.php` is inside `public` folder.

I use this kind of setup

```
<VirtualHost laravel4.dev>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel4/public"
    ServerName laravel4.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Corresponding setup in `windows/system32/drivers/etc/host` file is

```
127.0.0.2           ci.dev
127.0.0.3           laravel4.dev ## <-- This is for current vHost
127.0.0.4           symcom.dev
```

So, I can navigate to my site on local host using `http://laravel4.dev` (`dev` for development)

Comment: Wish I would have found this post when I was Googling this exact same issue... I put it together finally and it worked, but this would have saved me some grief!

Comment: @AVProgrammer, Wish you all the best and better luck next time and thanks for the thumbs up :-)

Comment: I did the same thing too. I thought pointing the vhost to the laravel installation folder `/example/` should be enough thinking Laravel routing will take care of moving all `/` urls to the public folder automatically. Guess I was wrong after reading this.

Comment: thank you so much. ıts working on wampserver

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly what you should be seeing. When you click the 'public' folder do you see a 'You have arrived.', with the laravel logo? If so, then you've correctly installed laravel.

The 'public' folder, is the main folder in which the actual public has access to your website when you put it on a server. You'll want to do one of two things here:

**The simple (but insecure) way:**

Add a .htaccess file to the root of your web folder containing this text:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will make all requests go to www.example.com/public, but only show www.example.com in the URL.

**The harder (but correct) way:**

This completely depends on which provider you will be hosting your website on, but on Godaddy and others, you have the option of selecting the root folder of your website. In this case you'd select the 'public' folder to be the root. I cannot give you a tutorial on that because this option ranges on availability on every hosting provider.

EDIT: I should add just in case. When you add content to your site, such as CSS/images/files and everything the public will have access to, make sure you put them in the public folder.

Answer (score 2):

You VirtualHost configuration needs to point `DirectoryRoot` further into `public/` directory, so it can use its `.htaccess` and `index.php` inside that directory.