# how to remove folder public in laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, xampp, url-rewriting

I have laravel setup on xampp located in `http://localhost/laravel`
but to test it I have to go to `localhost/laravel/public` 
How do I get rid of the /public ? 
I would like to be able to access it directly through `http://localhost/laravel`

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) and you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386249/laravel-not-showing-index-php/21387260#21387260) to setup a virtual host. Also you may use [this solution](http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/) but it's not recommended because it tells to move all files and folders from `public` to your app root folder.

Comment: I found the second option via google but I do not want to move the files to my app folder, the first one should work perfectly. thanks Sheikh!

Answer (score 1):

1. REMOVING .htaccess from root if you have created
2. take all files and folder from public to root directory
3. remove ../ from index.php
4. rename OR remove public folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this article. It explains why .htaccess is not the way to go, and offers two alternatives.
http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host