# Laravel Routes adding comma(,) in Url routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am using `Laravel 3` and it is adding a `comma(,)` on my server whereas it is working fine at my localhost.

The below code is working fine.

```
Route::get('/menu', function()
{
  return View::make('home.menu'); 

});
```

but having problem in redirection

```
Route::get('/cart-form', function()

if($total == 0){
   return Redirect::to('../../menu');
 }else{
  return Redirect::to('../../');
 }
});
```

Result in Url:

```
http://mydomain.com/test/public,/menu
                               ^-----------Comma
```

Comment: just an advice, go for laravel 4. it is more awesome ;)

Comment: Agreed with `itachi`, if you can go for `version-4.*`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
return Redirect::to('menu');
```

Also, you should use a virtual host and should not use `public` in `url`. Check following answers:

- [Setting up Virtual Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155671/laravel-setup-failed-to-open-stream/19156780#19156780)
- [How to remove folder public in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959128/how-to-remove-folder-public-in-laravel/21959267#21959267)