# 404 issue with Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am very confused as to why this is happening but here is the issue guys. Basically I am building an app using `laravel4` I want to go to this `URL`

```
http://app.tld/books
```

However I get this error every time:

```
404: The requested URL /books was not found on this server.
```

However in my `routes.php` file I have the route defined:

```
Route::get('/books', 'BookController@index');
```

I also have a view and relevent method in `Controller`:

```
public function index(){
        $books = Book::all();
        return View::make('book.index')->with('books', $books);
    }
```

Comment: In your vhost, do you have it pointing to the `/public` directory of the project, or just the project root?

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan dump-autoload` ? Maybe Laravel didn't yet see your BookController.

Comment: Probably you need to run `php artisan dump-autoload` from command prompt/terminal.

Comment: Yes it is pointing to `/public` and also ran the `dump auto-load` it is strange because in work I can run the project no problem. I've checked it out using `SVN` into `Netbeans`

Comment: Are you running it from `localhost`, what platform ?

Comment: `Wamp Server 2.5` and in work I know the version is `2.2`

Comment: Can you access `home` page ?

Comment: as in the default welcome page?

Comment: Try `php artisan routes` from command prompt and make sure that route exists and everything is right.

Comment: Yes, all `routes` listed

Comment: Can you post `BookController` class ?

Comment: Yes I will, also this `URL` is working..... `http://app.tld/index.php/books` could it be htaccess issue?

Comment: You didn't setup a `virtual host` right ? It's `.htaccess` yes.

Comment: I did, I can post that in question if you like

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled in apache?

Comment: Check this answer first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959128/how-to-remove-folder-public-in-laravel/21959267#21959267

Comment: Guys it was the `mod_rewrite` issue. I enabled it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments we gather that it was an Apache issue, not a Laravel issue (`mod_rewrite` wasn't enabled -- kudos to [@watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697370/watcher)), and I'm glad you sorted it out.

For future reference, it seemed likely to be an Apache issue because Laravel throws PHP exceptions on undefined routes, namely a `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException`. If you have `debug` set to `true` you'll get a neatly styled stack trace with code highlighting and server/request data, if not you'll get a neatly styled "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." message. If, on the other hand, you get a white screen with Times New Roman messages like "404: The requested URL /books was not found on this server.", Laravel isn't even starting up.

As the comments on your question show, there are many other clues which will tell you that it's not your Laravel routes, though from the code you posted and even the title of the question, you seemed to had narrowed it down to routes, which probably had you looking in the wrong place for a while.