# Virtual host in laravel-4

Tags: laravel-4, virtualhost

How Can i setup virtual host for laravel-4 ?
Previously I wrote some code and routes looked like -

Route::get('/', 'PageController@home');

Route::get('/home', 'PageController@about');

when I gave the url - `"http://localhost/laravel-master/public/"` I can see the home page but when tired `"http://localhost/laravel-master/public/about"` i got error saying url not found.

I tired configuring virtual host but ended up with the error - You don't have permission to access"url" on this server.

What is the correct way to do this ??

the path to my laravel folder is "C:\wamp\www\laravel-master"

and instead of using `"http://localhost/laravel-master/public/"` i wish to use url like "myapp" or so, So that when i use myapp I can see the home page and when I use "myapp/about" I can see the about page.

Comment: What value is set in `app/config/app.php` at line 29? By default it's `http://localhost`, try `http://localhost/laravel-master/public` instead.

Comment: yes it is wht u said but I dont want to have laravel-master/public in my url ..URL should be more clean !!

Comment: What is your definition of `clean URL`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386249/laravel-not-showing-index-php/21387260#21387260

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your virtualhost and host file.Make your apache listen to your Url.

Something like in your virtualhost file

```
<VirtualHost laravel>
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/laravel-master/public"
  ServerName laravel
</VirtualHost>
```

And in your host file:

```
  127.0.0.2  laravel
```

make apache restart and your clean URL will work.

Comment: and in this case and in this case in url "laravel" should show me the home page same as that I can see with http://localhost/laravel-master/public/